# How to assign selected to option depend on AJAX response in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying  to  get the value of select tag in html when AJAX response I tried a lot of solution but it didn't work.

Here is the JQuery Code :

```
$("#CitizenID").keyup(function(){
  $.getJSON("guarantorajax.php", {
    CitizenID: $("#CitizenID").val(), ajax: 'true'
  }, function(data){
    // var obj = JSON.stringify(data);
    var $BankBranchID = $("#BankBranchID");
    $BankBranchID.val(data["BankBranchID"]);
  });
});
```

I already try this way:

```
$("#BankBranchID option[value="+data['BankBranchID']+"]").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

and it didn't work too.
 HTML code :

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-2"> البنك <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <select class="form-control" name="BankID" id="BankID">
      <option value="-1" selected="true" disabled="disabled"> اختر البنك</option>
      <?php 
        $bank_sth = $constantsobj->getConstTable('bank');
        $count = 1;
        while($bank_row = $bank_sth->fetch()){
      ?>
      <option value=" <?php echo $bank_row["BankID"]; ?>"> <?php echo $bank_row["BankName"]; ?></option>
      <?php

      }
      ?>
    </select>
  </div>
    <label class="control-label col-md-1"> فرع <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <select class="form-control" name="BankBranchID" id="BankBranchID">
    </select>
  </div>

</div>
```

Can you please help me to do it in right way and thank you.

Comment: There is way too much code in there. You should demo the problem with minimal amount of code necessary that reproduces it. Also, you can select a value of a select list by saying `$('.myselect').val(someValue)`.

Comment: I notice that after posted it but I didn't find the edit button in the page to edit it , and your answer didn't help

Comment: What does `data['BankBranchID']` look like?  Use `console.log()` in your success callback to be 100% sure.

Comment: @Don'tPanic `data['BankBranchID']` is the response of ajax it's work for another input and show the right response of ajax , I even try to assign value from code and it doesn't work ether I did something like `$BankBranchID.val("2");`

Comment: Yes, I understand; I am asking what does it look like?  A number? A string?  Does it exactly match one of your `<option>`s?  `console.log()` it to triple-check.

Comment: yes it match the id is a number

Comment: How about `$('#BankBranchID option[value=' + data["BankBranchID"] + ']').prop('selected', true);` ?

Comment: Provide a [mcve]

Comment: yes , it didn't work

Comment: Show us your HTML.

Comment: I edit my Question add HTML the bank branch append from ajax depend  on the BankID , you can try example on BankID